# Is there a way to make sure child components fire actions after parent components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm having issues  when I try to fire an action within the useEffect hook defined at the entry point for my application. Lower in the component tree, I'm using the useEffect hook to make API calls that use a crucial piece of data being retrieved in the entry point I described. It seems that I would not want to move the fetching of that crucial piece of data down and into every child component that needs it. Am I using an anti-pattern here?

The only other option I can think of is not calling the API until that piece of data is retrieved, but for reusability purposes this is not a good way of doing things and provides a lot of potential issues.

The component tree is as follows:

```
<App> <-- useEffect hook retrieves crucial piece of data
    <Child /> <-- useEffect hook calls API with data
</App>
```

An error occurs because the route gets called without that crucial piece of data, but I have it set up to call the API again once that data is received. This is not a good solution and wastes another API call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do next.

1. Create context to provide information about parent initialization to child components.

```
const ParentInitializeContext = React.createContext(false);
```

2. Create a boolean state variable `isInitialized` in the parent component and set it to `true` when the parent component will initialize. You also have to provide `isInitialized` to context:

```
function App(props) {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //here you retreive a crucial piece of data and then call setIsInitialized(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <ParentInitializeContext.Provider value={isInitialized}>
      {props.children}
    </ParentInitializeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

3. Create own hook to call functions when parent component will initialize:

```
function useEffectWhenParentInitialized(fn, inputs = []) {
  const isParentInitialized = useContext(ParentInitializeContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isParentInitialized) {
      fn();
    }
  }, [...inputs, isParentInitialized]);
}
```

4. Change `useEffect` hook in child components to `useEffectWhenParentInitialized`.

You can view a full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5volk3o2ol